# fetch data in meteor based on sub element

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have issue regarding publishing collection.
I have model of each document in collection.

```
{
    "_id" : "8SwmMoMHTREDNDQTN",
    "persons" : [ 
        {
            "userId" : "29pr753gmyDxQZzo6",
            "lastReadTime":""
        }, 
        {
            "userId" : "gWKbYKiQsFzdCTwkz",
            "lastReadTime":""
        }
    ]
}
```

Now i want to publish document which persons.userId have current user id

Here is my publish code

```
Meteor.publish("chatRooms", function(){
   return userData.find({persons:{$elemMatch:{userId:this.userId}}});
});
```

But is it is nothing

i had also try below code

```
Meteor.publish("chatRooms", function(){
   return userData.find({"persons.userId":this.userId});
});
```

But also getting result data 0

How can i publish this way?

Comment: Take a look around for the many duplicates to this ( I know I will be ). Not the "query" part, but **instead** your problem is because you are trying to reference the "current user" when it is not actually in scope. That's the issue.

Comment: @NeilLunn : this.userId will give current logged in user id in meteor and it is giving

Comment: Meteor.publish("chatRooms", function(){
   return userData.find({"persons.userId":this.userId});
});
Will work, It's please console.log(this.userId); and check where it is present in your doc or not.

Comment: @BhaveshJariwala the last example seems correct. Double check that: (1) the user is logged in, (2) the database actually contains a matching document, (3) the documents are published to the client - open a browser console and run `userData.find().count()` after subscribing.

Comment: @DavidWeldon : i checked again user is logged in, database has already matching data because i user this query in robomongo and it is given expected result. on console it is giving count 0 on console